# NodeJS : What happen if not close oracle connection

Tags: node.js, oracle, memory

I'm building a NodeJS Application that will connect to an oracle Database.

I'm wondering what happen if I don't close connection and I call the `fiftycent()` function many times ?

```
var i=50;
function fiftycent() {
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

 oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : "welcome",
    connectString : "localhost/XE"
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    connection.execute(
      "SELECT department_id, department_name "
    + "FROM departments "
    + "WHERE department_id = :did",
      [180],
      function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
        console.log(result.rows);
      });
  });
 i=i-1;
 if (i>0) fiftycent();
}
```

After the node server is being running during days, will it cause memory failure or something like that ?

Please note that part of this example is taken from https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb and they don't include

```
connection.release( function(err){
 if (err) console.error(err.message);
});
```

in their code.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you call `getConnection` it creates a new (complete) connection to your db. If you don't call `release`it could lead to memory leaks in your application, because the connection is still allocated. And maybe depending on your db server settings, you could reach the maximum number of total open connections.

In this case it would be better to pool your connections in a `connection pool`. Calling `release` will return the connection to the pool and makes it available to other calls.

All the examples use the `release` function to free the connection. Take a look [here](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/250ef9c82db89cf3bdb42b057f596425f601da39/examples/select1.js#L63-71)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You're right !

After some tests I got this error :

TNS-12516 TNS:listener could not find instance with matching protocol stack.

Do you have some exemples of  "connection pool" ?

Comment: The connection pool has a complete web app example: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/250ef9c82db89cf3bdb42b057f596425f601da39/examples/webapp.js 
The documentation about the pool is https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/250ef9c82db89cf3bdb42b057f596425f601da39/doc/api.md#-4-pool-class

Comment: Hello ! Thanks very much.
I'm a newbe, I'm studying the scripts of your example and make some search on how to apply pool connexion to my needs.

First of all I thank you and I will come back when my problem is solved

Comment: Hello staaar. I understand now how connection pool work.
In my case when I release connection, I get an error : database connection lost. It's because node work assychronously.

How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get this error : err [Error: NJS-003: invalid connection]

Comment: Sorry, hard to tell what could be wrong with your code. In general: Keep in mind that node works in an asynchronous way. You have to use your callbacks to keep the operations valid e.g. close the connection only _AFTER_ your statement is executed. A great way to deal with the callbacks and the callback flow are npm modules like `bluebird` `async` they allow you to structure your code to keep something like a "flow" in your callbacks. But again, hard to tell what's wrong with your code and which callback execution could lead to this error.

Comment: Thank you very much for all. I'm mixing recursive and asynchronous programming. It's really hard. I keep on analysing my code I'm sure I find the what's wong. Have a nice day.
Thanks once more !!!

Comment: My problem was with recursion and asynchronous execution of node javascript code.
I undestand better now. I gonna try to solve my problem..

see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495032/recursion-callback-and-nodejs/30495276#30495276

Comment: should I connection.release or connection.close? seems like they use close in last version https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/select1.js